# Include either name or slug in the include parameter using wp_list_categories?

Tags: categories, tags

I'm working both locally and remotely, pushing code via git. I have the current code set up below, which looks for tags and outputs them as a list using `wp_list_categories`. I need to use the `include` parameter as there is no hierarchy with tags (I can't use categories in this instance).

However, as I am working locally and remotely, there's a chance that the IDs from local to remote won't be the same. So, ideally, I'd like to include by `name` or `slug`, but I know the `include` parameter only allows IDs.

Is there any way to include either `name` or `slug` in the `include` parameter?

Idea: My friend said we could have a list of names, and loop through them all and use get_term_by to get the id – but I'm not exactly sure where to start...

Thanks in advance,
R

```
<?php $sector_args = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
    'show_count' => 0,
    'pad_counts' => 0,
    'title_li' => '',
    'include' => '5,6,7'
); ?>

<ul>
    <?php wp_list_categories( $sector_args ); ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to figure this out with help from a friend. In case this helps anyone else, here's my code.

```
<?php $sector_terms = array('animal-health', 'sustainability-science', 'technical-publishing');
$sector_ids = array_map( function( $sector_term )
{ $st = get_term_by('slug', $sector_term , 'post_tag'); return $st->term_id; }, $sector_terms); ?>

<?php $sector_args = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
    'show_count' => 0,
    'pad_counts' => 0,
    'title_li' => '',
    'include' => $sector_ids
); ?>

<ul>
    <?php wp_list_categories( $sector_args ); ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: [There is a query](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.7.1/src/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L1030) every time `get_term_by` runs. This is a functional answer but if your list is long you could see performance problems.

Comment: @s_ha_dum Thanks for this. Any help with an alternative solution?